# Mapper is not producing expected results

Tags: mapreduce

This is my input file (custs.txt):

> 1002|surender|23 
>    1003|Rahja|24

And this is my program:

**Main:**

```
public class ReduceSideJoinMain {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException,    ClassNotFoundException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    JobConf config = new JobConf();
    config.setQueueName("omega");

    Job job = new Job(config,"word count");

    job.setJarByClass(ReduceSideJoinMain.class);

    Path inputFilePath1 = new Path(args[0]);
    Path outputFilePath2 = new Path(args[1]);

    //MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath1, TextInputFormat.class,CustMapper.class);
    //MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath2, TextInputFormat.class,TxnsMapper.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFilePath1);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputFilePath2);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(CustMapper.class);
    //job.setReducerClass(ReduceJoinMapper.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

}
```

**Mapper**:

```
public class CustMapper  extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>
{
public static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.InterruptedException
    {

    String line =   value.toString();


    String arr[]=   line.split("|");
    context.write(new Text(arr[0]), new Text(arr[1]));

    }
}
```

I am getting the following output, which is wrong:

```
        1
        1
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
1002    surender
1003    Rahja
```

Why is it not giving the expected output? Is there any issue with Split method?

Answer (score 1):

use `String arr[] = line.split("\\|");`

Comment: Perfect.. i tried it and it got resolved and i also i came to know what is the root cause . thanks a lot